# Remove Tomcat completely from Centos 7

Tags: centos, centos7, yum

I want to remove tomcat from my centos 7. I already removed it with yum but its still there.

```
 sudo service tomcat status
```

- Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status tomcat.service
- tomcat.service - Tomcat 9 servlet container
- Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
- Active: active (running) since Tue 2020-06-02 16:57:54 CEST; 6s ago
- Process: 24809 ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.30/bin/startup.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
- Main PID: 24816 (java)
- CGroup: /system.slice/tomcat.service
         └─24816 /usr/lib/jvm/jre/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.30/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom -Djdk.tls....

`[root@localhost share]$ sudo rpm -qa | grep tomcat`

- tomcat-lib-7.0.76-11.el7_7.noarch
- tomcat-javadoc-7.0.76-11.el7_7.noarch
- tomcat-servlet-3.0-api-7.0.76-11.el7_7.noarch
- tomcat-el-2.2-api-7.0.76-11.el7_7.noarch
- tomcat-jsp-2.2-api-7.0.76-11.el7_7.noarch

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Does nobody have an idea, anything?